# Fixed points of an automorphism and a meromorphic map.

Tags: riemann-surfaces

I want to solve this problem

> Let $X$ a compact Riemann surface and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ a non constant meromorphic function in $X$. Let $h\in\text{Aut }(X) $ and automorphism of finite order $\text{ord } (h)$. If the number of fixed points of $h$ is bigger than $2\,\text {deg }(f)$ then $f=f\circ h$ and $\text {deg } (f)$ is a multiple of $\text {ord }{h}$.

I've been playing around with the Riemann-Hurwitz equations without arriving to something useful.

Any hint?

Comment: What is grad(f)?

Comment: Oups. I meant deg(f).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is holomorphic $X\to\Bbb{P}^1$ and meromorphic $X\to\Bbb{C}$.

Composing $f$ with a Möbius transformation we can assume the given fixed points of $h$ are not poles of $f$.

How many zeros does $f-f\circ h$ have ? How many poles does $f$ thus $f\circ h$ have ?

Comment: I know that $f-f\circ h$ has at least as many zeros as fixed points $h$ has. 
$f$ has $\text{deg }(f)$ poles and $f\circ h$ has the same number of poles.
... But it is still unclear to me how to continue.

Comment: So $f-f \circ h$ has $\ge 2\deg(f) +1$ zeros and $\le 2\deg(f)$ poles. A non-zero meromorphic function on a compact Riemann surface has the same number of zeros & poles.